# certificate not authenticated c#

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate

I have application which calls the web service. the return value is following:-
`****certificate  not authenticated****`

the web config is as follows:-

```
<clientCertificate findValue="Name" storeLocation="localMachine" storeName="my" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" >
```

pardon me for my spelling mistakes . not allowed to copy paste on this machine

Comment: should `findValue="Name"` be replace with the subject you're looking for?

Comment: ya, i have the complete cert name there. not able to copy paste here

Comment: you are searching by Subject not friendly name. so it should match the subject. Might look something like "CN=DigiCert Global Root CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US" also might need to play around with the formatting. From memory you would use comma to delimit instead of a newline and should have no space between the 'CN=xxx' etc

Comment: Searching on this doco https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0 it looks like the search does a contains so it might be fine to just give it the Common Name without worrying about the exact format for the full subject. you could also call the same functionality in a unit test or code scratchpad to see if it's able to find the certificate. Another reason it might be failing to find it is if you don't have access from the running account. especially if you need the private key.

Comment: I did some testing and it looks like it can't find the certificate when you include CN= so my above comment is wrong. You probably should just use the raw common name. Heres the code I played with which could help you debug. e.g. play around with find types and permission flags. `var store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);` 
`store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);` 
`var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localhost", false);`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. There is no code using certification directly. Three is a WCF service which calls the SSL web service. the web.config has this there>
<binding><security mode="Transport"><transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" /></security><binding>

Comment: I just mean you can use that code to test. It will make similar calls automatically when you configure via the web.config.